Nginx config for laravel + vue (some domain)
I have domain: site.com (work front vue)
I want use for api directory /api (site.com/api)
My current config
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name site.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/site/site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/site/site.key;

    root /home/user/workspace/site-frontend/dist; #front

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #api
    location /api {
        alias /home/user/workspace/site/public; # back
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}

as result i have 405 when request site.com/api/login with post (but endpoint corrects work locally)

Try changing from:
try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;

to:
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

